# Posting xml to a rest api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, web-services, rest

I need to post some xml info to a restful api can anyone give me a clue of how to do this? I'm using rails.

Answer (score 2):

In rails, using ActiveResource, you do it like this:

```
class PersonResource < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.people.com:3000/"
  self.proxy = "http://user:password@proxy.people.com:8080"
end

ryan = Person.new(:first => 'Ryan', :last => 'Daigle')
# the next line posts this object serialized to xml to the configured url
ryan.save                # => true
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

If the site you are posting to has a custom API (not active resource) you must use [Net:HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html)